# How to use FormsModule in other modules but app module?

Tags: angular

I am trying to add FormsModule in my myform.module.ts but it is not working and showing me this error.

```
 error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'
```

What I have done so far:

myform.module.ts

[image: myform.module.ts]

And this is the HTML file.

[image]

When I am doing the same on app.module.ts it is working properly. But not in any other module which I have created.

I have tried every possible way I found on google but nothing is working. My angular version is 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the `FormsModule`:

```
exports: [
  FormsModule
]
```